# Programmatically creating ArcGIS Image Service and adding it to map using C# / .NET?

Tags: arcgis-server, arcobjects, c#, .net, image-service

How can I programmatically create ArcGIS Image Service and add that service to my MXD file programmatically?

I am using C# .Net.

Answer (score 2):

There is a [Publish an image service and set configurations](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/arcobjects-net/conceptualhelp/index.html#//000100000262000000) sample for the SDK:

> This sample shows how to programmatically publish an image service to
>   ArcGIS 10.1 for Server. It illustrates how to connect to a server
>   admin endpoint, create an image service and set parameters and
>   capabilities based on data source type (mosaic dataset, raster
>   dataset, raster layer), and enable Web Coverage Service (WCS) and Web
>   Map Service (WMS). Additional functionalities include starting,
>   stopping, and deleting an image service.